# How to change a vector of strings to substrings derived from splitting the string?

Tags: r

How to change a vector of strings to substrings derived from splitting the string

An example vector:

```
test <- c("1.folder/file1.csv","1.folder/file2.csv","1.folder/file3.csv")
```

Desired output:

```
"file1.csv","file2.csv","file3.csv"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to just use `basename`:

```
basename(test)
## [1] "file1.csv" "file2.csv" "file3.csv"
```

`basename` also has a counterpart `dirname` that would give you the part that comes before the file name.

Answer (score 4):

An option with `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(test, whitespace = ".*/")
#[1] "file1.csv" "file2.csv" "file3.csv"
```

Comment: That's a clever use of the `trimws` function. Extra points since it will work for longer file paths too.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
test <- c("1.folder/file1.csv","1.folder/file2.csv","1.folder/file3.csv")
sub(".*/", "", test)
```

```
[1] "file1.csv" "file2.csv" "file3.csv"
```

Comment: No need for the `?` in your pattern

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(test, "file\\d\\.csv")
[1] "file1.csv" "file2.csv" "file3.csv"
```

Alternatively, using `sub`and backreference `\\1`to recall the substring inside the capturing group `(...)`:

```
sub(".*/(.*)$", "\\1", test)
[1] "file1.csv" "file2.csv" "file3.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but using your example:

```
test <- c("1.folder/file1.csv","1.folder/file2.csv","1.folder/file3.csv")
stringr::str_split(test, '/') %>% 
      purrr::map(., 2)
```

If you are trying to find files on your desktop, list.files() might be better.